# I want the time to show based on the selection on the 2nd drop down list

Tags: javascript

I have collated 2 different codes. 1st is a dropdown list of timezone that will show the current time for that specific TZ. the other one is it will show a different timezone for a specific capital and other cities if a specific Timezone is selected on the 2nd dropdown.

What I want to happen is time showing on the html page will be dependent on the 2nd dropdown list selection and still maintaining the clock running.

```js
var link = document.getElementById('ct2');
link.style.visibility = 'hidden';

function disp_TZ() {
  tz = ' '
  tz = f1.tz.options[f1.tz.options.selectedIndex].value
  str = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: tz,
    timeZoneName: "short"
  })


  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = str + " ,<br> " + tz

  dt2 = new Date();
  str2 = new Date(dt2.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: tz
  }));

  diff = dt2.getTime() - str2.getTime();
  dt3 = new Date(dt2.getTime() - diff);
  hour = dt3.getHours();
  minute = dt3.getMinutes();
  seconds = dt3.getSeconds();
  str3 = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + seconds
  document.getElementById('ct2').innerHTML = str3
  display_c()
}

function display_c() {
  refresh = 1000
  mytime = setTimeout('disp_TZ()', refresh)
}
var my_timezones = [
  'None Selected ',
  'Asia/Manila',
  'Canada/Eastern',
  'Canada/Atlantic',
  'Canada/Central',
  'Canada/Pacific',
  'Canada/Mountain',
  'Canada/Newfoundland'

]
for (i = 0; i < my_timezones.length; i++) {
  addOption(document.f1.tz, my_timezones[i], my_timezones[i])
}

function addOption(selectbox, text, value) {
  var optn = document.createElement("OPTION")
  optn.text = text
  optn.value = value
  selectbox.options.add(optn)
}



var opt = document.getElementById('test');
opt.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('t1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t4').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t5').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t6').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t7').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t' + this.value).style.display = '';
}

function hideTable() {
  document.getElementById('t1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t4').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t5').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t6').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t7').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('t' + this.value).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#ct {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<span id=ct></span><br>
<span id=ct2></span><br>

<form name=f1>
  <select name=tz onChange=disp_TZ()>
  </select>
</form>

<p>Select Timezone above</p>


<br><br>

<body onload="hideTable()">

  <select name="test" id="test" size="1">
    <option value="0">None Selected</option>
    <option value="1">Asia/Manila</option>
    <option value="2">Canada/Eastern</option>
    <option value="3">Canada/Atlantic</option>
    <option value="4">Canada/Central</option>
    <option value="5">Canada/Pacific</option>
    <option value="6">Canada/Mountain</option>
    <option value="7">Canada/Newfoundland</option>
  </select>

  <table id="t1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Capital</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Philippines</td>
      <td>Manila</td>

    </tr>

  </table>

  <table id="t2" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Province/Territory</th>
      <th> Time Zone</th>
      <th> Capital</th>
      <th> Other Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Ontario</td>
      <td> Eastern</td>
      <td> Toronto</td>
      <td> Ottawa, Mississauga, <br>Hamilton, Kitchener, <br>London, Oshawa, <br>Windsor, Barrie, <br>Guelph, Kingston, <br>Sudbury, Thunder Bay, <br>Etobicoke</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Quebec</td>
      <td> Eastern</td>
      <td> Quebec City</td>
      <td> Montreal, Sherbrooke, <br>Trois-Rivières, Chicoutimi, <br>Châteauguay, Granby</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Nunavut</td>
      <td> Eastern</td>
      <td> Iqaluit</td>
      <td> Cambridge Bay, Rankin Inlet</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="t3" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Province/Territory</th>
      <th> Time Zone</th>
      <th> Capital</th>
      <th> Other Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Nova Scotia</td>
      <td> Atlantic</td>
      <td> Halifax</td>
      <td> Cape Breton, Sydney, <br>Truro, Dartmouth </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> New Brunswick</td>
      <td> Atlantic</td>
      <td> Fredericton</td>
      <td> Moncton, Saint John, <br>Fredericton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Prince Edward Island</td>
      <td> Atlantic</td>
      <td> Charlottetown</td>
      <td> Summerside, Stratford</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="t4" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Province/Territory</th>
      <th> Time Zone</th>
      <th> Capital</th>
      <th> Other Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Manitoba</td>
      <td> Central</td>
      <td> Winnipeg</td>
      <td> Brandon, Churchill, <br>Steinbach, Winkler, <br>Portage La Prairie, Thompson</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="t5" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Province/Territory</th>
      <th> Time Zone</th>
      <th> Capital</th>
      <th> Other Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> British Columbia</td>
      <td> Pacific</td>
      <td> Victoria</td>
      <td> Vancouver, Surrey, <br>Burnaby, Richmond, <br>Abbotsford, Coquitlam, <br>Kelowna, Nanaimo, <br>Kamloops</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Yukon</td>
      <td> Pacific</td>
      <td> Whitehorse</td>
      <td> Cambridge Bay, Rankin Inlet</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="t6" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Province/Territory</th>
      <th> Time Zone</th>
      <th> Capital</th>
      <th> Other Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Saskatchewan</td>
      <td> Mountain</td>
      <td> Regina</td>
      <td> Saskatoon, Moose Jaw, <br>Swift Current, Yorkton</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Alberta</td>
      <td> Mountain</td>
      <td> Edmonton</td>
      <td> Calgary, Red Deer, <br>Lethbridge, Airdrie, <br>Medicine Hat, Grande Prairie, <br>Banff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Northwest Territories</td>
      <td> Mountain</td>
      <td> Yellowknife</td>
      <td> Inuvik</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="t7" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Province/Territory</th>
      <th> Time Zone</th>
      <th> Capital</th>
      <th> Other Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Newfoundland and Labrador</td>
      <td> Newfoundland</td>
      <td> St. John's</td>
      <td> Corner Brook, Grand Falls-Windsor, <br>Gander</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

Comment: I would first correct your error in the code that you've posted and then edit your question to more clearly ask about a specific issue. Right now, you've told us what you want, but haven't told us how far you've gotten or what particular thing you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a lot of changes. Study them since they are useful

- I removed the static select. You already had this
- The script needs to be after the HTML or we need to use a load eventListener: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded,{/* all the code */})`
- I streamlined a lot of the code so we do not repeat ourselves (DRY)

```js
var link = document.getElementById('ct2');
link.style.visibility = 'hidden';

const sel = document.querySelector("[name=tz]");



const disp_TZ = () => {
  const tz = sel.value;
  str = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
    timeZone: tz,
    timeZoneName: "short"
  })


  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = str + " ,<br> " + tz

  dt2 = new Date();
  str2 = new Date(dt2.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: tz
  }));

  diff = dt2.getTime() - str2.getTime();
  dt3 = new Date(dt2.getTime() - diff);
  hour = dt3.getHours();
  minute = dt3.getMinutes();
  seconds = dt3.getSeconds();
  str3 = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + seconds
  document.getElementById('ct2').innerHTML = str3
  display_c()
};

var my_timezones = [
  'None Selected ',
  'Asia/Manila',
  'Canada/Eastern',
  'Canada/Atlantic',
  'Canada/Central',
  'Canada/Pacific',
  'Canada/Mountain',
  'Canada/Newfoundland'

]


const tables = document.querySelectorAll("table[id^=t]"); // or use the same class on each
const toggleStyle = () => {
  const idx = sel.selectedIndex;

  tables.forEach(table => table.hidden = table.id != `t${idx}`);
};

my_timezones.forEach(tz => {
  let opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.text = tz;
  opt.value = tz;
  sel.appendChild(opt)
});


const display_c = () => {
  refresh = 1000
  mytime = setTimeout(disp_TZ, refresh)
}



sel.addEventListener("change", disp_TZ)
sel.addEventListener("change", toggleStyle)
toggleStyle()
```

```css
#ct {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

td,
th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<span id=ct></span><br>
<span id=ct2></span><br>

<select name="tz">
</select>

<p>Select Timezone above</p>


<br><br>




<table id="t1" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Capital</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Philippines</td>
    <td>Manila</td>

  </tr>

</table>

<table id="t2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Province/Territory</th>
    <th> Time Zone</th>
    <th> Capital</th>
    <th> Other Cities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Ontario</td>
    <td> Eastern</td>
    <td> Toronto</td>
    <td> Ottawa, Mississauga, <br>Hamilton, Kitchener, <br>London, Oshawa, <br>Windsor, Barrie, <br>Guelph, Kingston, <br>Sudbury, Thunder Bay, <br>Etobicoke</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Quebec</td>
    <td> Eastern</td>
    <td> Quebec City</td>
    <td> Montreal, Sherbrooke, <br>Trois-Rivières, Chicoutimi, <br>Châteauguay, Granby</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Nunavut</td>
    <td> Eastern</td>
    <td> Iqaluit</td>
    <td> Cambridge Bay, Rankin Inlet</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t3" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Province/Territory</th>
    <th> Time Zone</th>
    <th> Capital</th>
    <th> Other Cities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Nova Scotia</td>
    <td> Atlantic</td>
    <td> Halifax</td>
    <td> Cape Breton, Sydney, <br>Truro, Dartmouth </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> New Brunswick</td>
    <td> Atlantic</td>
    <td> Fredericton</td>
    <td> Moncton, Saint John, <br>Fredericton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Prince Edward Island</td>
    <td> Atlantic</td>
    <td> Charlottetown</td>
    <td> Summerside, Stratford</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t4" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Province/Territory</th>
    <th> Time Zone</th>
    <th> Capital</th>
    <th> Other Cities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Manitoba</td>
    <td> Central</td>
    <td> Winnipeg</td>
    <td> Brandon, Churchill, <br>Steinbach, Winkler, <br>Portage La Prairie, Thompson</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t5" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Province/Territory</th>
    <th> Time Zone</th>
    <th> Capital</th>
    <th> Other Cities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> British Columbia</td>
    <td> Pacific</td>
    <td> Victoria</td>
    <td> Vancouver, Surrey, <br>Burnaby, Richmond, <br>Abbotsford, Coquitlam, <br>Kelowna, Nanaimo, <br>Kamloops</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Yukon</td>
    <td> Pacific</td>
    <td> Whitehorse</td>
    <td> Cambridge Bay, Rankin Inlet</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t6" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Province/Territory</th>
    <th> Time Zone</th>
    <th> Capital</th>
    <th> Other Cities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Saskatchewan</td>
    <td> Mountain</td>
    <td> Regina</td>
    <td> Saskatoon, Moose Jaw, <br>Swift Current, Yorkton</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Alberta</td>
    <td> Mountain</td>
    <td> Edmonton</td>
    <td> Calgary, Red Deer, <br>Lethbridge, Airdrie, <br>Medicine Hat, Grande Prairie, <br>Banff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Northwest Territories</td>
    <td> Mountain</td>
    <td> Yellowknife</td>
    <td> Inuvik</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="t7" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th> Province/Territory</th>
    <th> Time Zone</th>
    <th> Capital</th>
    <th> Other Cities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Newfoundland and Labrador</td>
    <td> Newfoundland</td>
    <td> St. John's</td>
    <td> Corner Brook, Grand Falls-Windsor, <br>Gander</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: WOW, thank you so much @mplungjan, appreciate your help on this.